# unity Lerp alpha of text and keep the original color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I attempted to make a pingponging colored text for my splash screen. I attempted to just change the alpha value and my color turned black on run-time. When attempting to assign a color in the function, it turned white instead. Can you guys please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how I should set the color properly?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LerpAlpha : MonoBehaviour {

    public float duration;
    float alpha;
    Text colorText;
    Color textColor;

    void LerpAlphaText()
    {
        float lerp = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, duration) / duration;
        alpha = Mathf.Lerp(0.0f, 1.0f, Mathf.SmoothStep(0.0f, 1.0f, lerp));
        textColor.a = alpha;
        ///Also tried textColor = new Color(113, 75, 2, alpha); resulting in 
        ///the white text             
        colorText.color = textColor;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        colorText = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        LerpAlphaText();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RGBA components of the `Color` class have a range of 0-1, so `Color(113, 75, 2, alpha)` will return white. Either scale your components by *RGBA/255.0* or simply change `Color textColor;` to `public Color textColor;` and set it in the Inspector.

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought the range was 0-255.

Comment: `Color32` has range of 255 but the `.color` property you're setting is of type `Color` so although Color32 could be used, it'll require an implicit conversion which isn't free.